# Take screenshot and copy its file path to clipboard

Tags: keyboard, screen-capture

I want to have the file path of a screenshot to be available in the clipboard to paste it directly into some text. Greenshot on Windows can do this in just one keyboard shortcut simultaneously taking the screenshot and putting its file path into the clipboard. How can this be done in Mac?

Comment: Note that if you just need to get the path into a terminal or a plain-text-only field, you can just drag and drop the created screenshot from the screenshot preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign a shortcut to a script like this:

```
f=~/Desktop/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png
screencapture -i $f
osascript -e 'set the clipboard to POSIX file "'$f'"'
```

One way to do that is to create a service in Automator:

[image]

Then give the service a keyboard shortcut from System Preferences.

If you just want to copy the path as text, replace the last line with `printf %s $f | pbcopy`.

Comment: What is the benefit of using AppleScript to set the clipboard? Is the result not the same as `pbcopy` anyway?

Comment: @patrix pbcopy flattens complex objects into the clipboard as text by default. AppleScript is better for more general purpose pasting where the object could be interpreted as plain text, styled text, several resolution images, etc... http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070416161655621 In this case, it's probably moot though.